# Bower install without Git

Tags: angularjs, bower, jhipster

I am generating a monolithic application with Jhipster with Oracle as the database with Yarn and generate-Jhipster. Below are the commands we executed and attached the package.json, bower.json, yo-rc.json and .bowercc files.

1. `yarn add global bower`
2. `yarn add global gulp-cli`
3. `yarn add global generator-jhipster`
4. `jhipster` (Throws exception while bower install as below)

   [image: Error Message while executing the command **Bower install**]
5. `Gulp` (Throws the same above exception)
6. The bower_Components folder is not present as a result of the above without which the application is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Bower requires git. https://bower.io/#install-bower

If you don’t want JHipster to initialize a git repository, use the `-—skip-git` flag when generating